# 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml, pyjwt

Getting error 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers when installing a package with pip. The package is an internal package but seems to error when installing one of the dependencies. Any idea how to solve this error?

My python version is 3.8.2, pip version 23.1.2, mac OS Ventura 13.1

Here is a little more info on the error

```
Running command Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
  error in lasso setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
      PyJWT>=1<2
```

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in the pyproject.toml of the internal package. `PyJWT>=1<2` isn't a valid requirement specifier. It's probably meant to be `>=1,<2` or `>=1.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `PyJWT>=1<2`  is not correct versioning in pyproject.toml

You can write it as follows:

```
PyJWT >= 1, < 2
```

or

```
PyJWT = "^1.0.0"
```

Comment: thanks, I updated the syntax and was able to install the package now

Answer (score 0):

From: [pip install -e . fails with "Expected end or semicolon" for git+https in requirements, but pip install -r succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76784012/pip-install-e-fails-with-expected-end-or-semicolon-for-githttps-in-require)

It looks like setuptools requires the package name to be supplied as a prefix, then the fetch URL after an @, e.g.

```
# requirements.txt
mypackage @ git+https://github.com/myorg/myrepo@v1.0.0#egg=mypackage
```