# pip install -e . fails with "Expected end or semicolon" for git+https in requirements, but pip install -r succeeds

Tags: python, pip

I have a `requirements.txt` that uses `git+https` URLs like

```
git+https://github.com/myorg/myrepo@v1.0.0#egg=mypackage
```

This installs fine with `pip install -r requirements.txt` .

But if I reference it in my `setup.cfg`:

```
[options]
install_requires = file: requirements.txt
```

and `pip install -e .` my package as an editable install from a local dir for development, `pip` fails with:

```
  Getting requirements to build editable ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
      [...snip...]
      setuptools.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          git+https://github.com/myorg/myrepo@v1.0.0#egg=mypackage
```

despite the same `requirements.txt` being valid for `-r` . What's up?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `setuptools` requires the package name to be supplied as a prefix, then the fetch URL after an `@`, e.g.

```
# requirements.txt
mypackage @ git+https://github.com/myorg/myrepo@v1.0.0#egg=mypackage
```

This form is accepted by `pip install -e .` with a `setup.cfg` that indirectly references the `requirements.txt`,  and by `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

It might be relevant that my project uses `setuptools-scm`.

Comment: thanks Craig! this saved me from a sleepless night.